# in C: Is void* a type?

Tags: c, pointers

In some discussions it's claimed that void* is "pointer to void object" but in C standard 6.5.3.4, point 2 it is written:
"The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes)....The size is determined from the type of the operand."
So it is stated that function sizeof() receives a type as arguments.

So the compiler considers void* a type? or the use of * it's only for semantical interpretation?

Comment: Why don't you trust the standard?

Comment: Yes, `void*` is a type. Not sure what the actual question is.

Comment: `int*` and `int` are both types, which is why `sizeof(int*)` and `sizeof(int)` both work.

Comment: @DYZ Because i see different claiming about this, so i ask myself if void* is a token (a type in this case) or is void + *. Why i ask myself? That's a good question my friend...i guess i just like to understand the things well...

Comment: Is there something that makes you think being a type and being a pointer are mutually exclusive?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons In my world of doubt yes. For example the fact that "void* ptr" and "void     *      ptr" both work and that void* and void** are both addresses containers, so i wonder why to make them to be declared in different manners...By the way i am not experienced so to me, everything makes me rise doubts...

Comment: Rule of thumb: many discussions are hogwash but the C standard is concrete. So in a dispute trust the latter.

Comment: `void* ptr` and `void * ptr` are identical.  As is `void *ptr`.  The white-space is inconsequential.  I'm not sure what you are getting at with the comparison of `void*` and `void**`.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons if void* is a pointer type and void** is also a pointer type, "holding" the same size of a void type, i cannot really see a semantical difference, but since sizeof() accepts a type, than void* and void** has to different types, but i have no idea in what they differs.

Comment: `void*` is a pointer to a `void`.  `void**` is a pointer to `void *`.  So they are both pointers, but that is only part of their type.  What they point to is also a part of their type.

Comment: @Paolo There is a semantic difference between `void*` and `void**`. The latter has more information about the value than the former one. And that distinction is important for type safety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`void *` is indeed a type.  So is `void`.

`void` is an *incomplete* type that cannot be completed - it represents an empty set of values.  Because it is an incomplete type, it may not be the operand of the `sizeof` operator.  Therefore, `void` (logically) has no size, and you cannot create an object of `void` type.

`void *` is a pointer type, and as such it is a complete type.  It acts as a "generic" pointer type, and can be converted to other pointer types without a cast.  You cannot dereference a `void *`, since the result would have type `void`, and you cannot have an object of type `void` - you must first convert it to a pointer to a complete type.

`void *` has the same size and representation as a `char *`.

Answer (score 5):

A `void *` is a valid type that has a known size.  What it points to is either some object whose type is not known or valid untyped memory (i.e. memory returned from `malloc`).  As such `sizeof(void *)` is a valid expression.

Paragraph 1 of 6.5.3.4 states:

> **The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has
>   function type or an incomplete  type,  to  the  parenthesized  name 
>   of  such  a  type**,  or  to  an  expression  that designates  a 
>   bit-field  member.   The
>   `_Alignof` operator  shall  not  be  applied  to  a function type or an incomplete type.

Because `void *` is not an incomplete type, `sizeof(void *)` is valid.  However, because `void` type is incomplete, `sizeof(void)` is invalid.

Addressing your comment about `void **`, that is also a valid type which points to an object of type `void *`.

Some compilers such as GCC implement an extension where `void` has a size of 1 , so `sizeof(void) == 1` and pointer arithmetic on a `void *` functions in a similar manner to arithmetic on a `char *`.  This however goes against the standard.

Comment: As far as i knew, void* pointers did not allow for arithmetic ops like using ++ operator, but today trying some code, the operation was executed and the address pointed increased of 1byte...rising me so much question since from some discussions, was written the void was the type (incomplete) and * was only a sintax to "generate" the proper pointer, avoiding to state that void* is actually a type itself. Thanks for explanation dbush

Comment: @Paolo See my update.  Some compilers allow it as an extension.

Comment: In design C programs you would advise to follows strict C standards or GNU? Why does GNU prefer to officially brake ANSI C?

Comment: @Paolo Generally you should follow the standard.  The only time I'd recommend using extensions is if your program by its nature is restricted to some specific hardware or OS.

Comment: @paolo: defining behaviour which is not defined by the standard does not break anything. The standard does not prohibit undefined behaviour; it merely fails to define the consequences. So GCC (and other compilers) are free to extend the standard, and you are free to use those extensions if you don't care about portability.